# Can I travel with a bike with n-days GVB cards in Amsterdam?

Tags: trains, bicycles, amsterdam

Looking at the GVB.nl site, the GVB 1 day (24 hours) costs € 7.50.
If I have that should I buy an Bicycle supplement ​€ 1.60 for each time I want to embark with my bike?

What if I bought GVB 7 days (168 hours) € 32.00, should I buy 14 Bicycle supplements if I plan to embark twice a day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pertinent information is [here on the gvb.nl site](http://www.gvb.nl/reisinformatie/welke-kaart/Pages/Fiets-mee.aspx), in Dutch.

Bicycles are only allowed in the *metro* (subway) and in *tram line 26*, not in other tram lines or bus lines. GVB also doesn't have any trains, if you want to take the bicycle on a train, you'll need different tickets entirely (both for yourself and for the bike).

The GVB supplement is valid for an entire day (so doesn't depend on the number of times you embark), but *not during rush hour*: bicycles aren't allowed between 7:00-9:00 and 16:00-18:30. This is the rule in trains as well, by the way.

In tram 26 you can buy a paper supplement at the driver, otherwise the ticket has to be loaded onto an "OV chipkaart" at a machine.

I feel the need to add -- if you have a bicycle, why not just ride it :-)

Comment: the site says a disposable fiet supplement is only available at tram 26. does it mean that I can't enter with a bike in a metro if I only have 1-day ticket?